# Dynamic DocumentRoot Based on SSL (Client Auth.)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently use Client SSL authentication to protect sensitive content. Users are required to import a certificate into their browsers that we generated using OpenSSL. When a user visits the website, we redirect them to a custom 403 page if they don't have the certificate in their browser or operating system's keychain. This is achieved using the following Apache configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName host.tld
    ServerAlias www.host.tld

    ServerAdmin servers@host.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/host/host.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/host.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
#   SSLCARevocationPath /etc/ssl/crl
    SSLCARevocationFile /etc/ssl/ca.crl
    SSLCARevocationCheck chain

    RewriteEngine        on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond     %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !=SUCCESS
    RewriteRule     .? - [F]
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
    
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to take this a step further and introduce some conditionals to load a specific DocumentRoot if they have the certificate present, or another DocumentRoot if they don't have the client certificate.

**In summary:  website.com**

- User A visits with client SSL, serve website.com from /var/www/has_ssl
- User B visits without client SSL, serve website.com
  from /var/www/no_ssl

I can use `%{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} =""` to redirect to a path if empty, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the DocumentRoot based on the presence of the certificate.

I've been struggling with this for a few days. Any assistance or pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't conditionally set the `DocumentRoot`. However, you could internally rewrite the request using mod_rewrite, in much the same way you are returning a 403 response when the client SSL is not set.

For example, if you set:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Then internally rewrite all requests to `/var/www/has_ssl` on success or `/var/www/no_ssl` otherwise.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !=SUCCESS
RewriteRule ^ /no_ssl%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} =SUCCESS
RewriteRule ^ /has_ssl%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

To prevent direct access to either the `/no_ssl` or `/has_ssl` subdirectories you could implement an external redirect *before* the above rewrites that removes the subdirectory from the request. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/(no_ssl|has_ssl)(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it helped me setup the verification using sub-directories. This works for now, however I'll be looking at Nginx to see if the root can be set conditionally. I'll update this with a link if I find a solution to help others.